# Как указать корневой каталог удаленного сервера в шаге сборки Jenkins?

Tags: java, ssh, jenkins

Задача состоит в том, чтобы с помощью Jenkins собрать war файл и скопировать его на удаленный сервер.

Сборка и копирование - работают, но
вместо вместо того, чтобы war-файл попал в нужную директорию на удаленном сервере /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.30/webapps, файл попадает в home - директорию.(home/%user%/opt...)

Как это можно исправить?

Jenkins использую не только я, поэтому вариант с установкой глобальных переменных на самом сервере Jenkins думаю является неприемлемым.

Мои настройки Jenkins:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй абсолютный путь в remote directory указать, ты забыл в начале "/". То есть /opt/
Также не забудь права на opt соответствующие выставить

Comment: Идея хорошая, но не помогло - скопировалось туда же, в home.

Comment: двойной слеш помог , то есть //opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.30/webapps